# Celery tasks vanishing - Django/Celery

Tags: python, django, message-queue, celery

here is my code:

#### my task

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

#### using my tasks

```
from core.tasks import add

results = []

for i in range(100):
    results.append(add.delay(i, i))
```

---

#### problem 1

after a few seconds I perform the following:

```
for result in results:
    print result.result
```

#### prints this:

(the values are not returned in what looks like a pattern)

```
None
None
None
None
8
None
None
None
None
18
None
None
None
None
28
None
None
None
None
38
...
```

### Second clean OS install+setup:

everything is working as expected, still not sure what happened here...

---

Tasks are also randomly missing within the Django admin interface...

---

Anybody know what is going on? :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task.delay() is asynchronous. BTW, the whole AMQP thing is about making tasks asynchronous. If you want synchronous behavior, what is the point of using celery?

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y, results):
    results.append(x + y)

------------8<-------------
from core.tasks import add

results = []

for i in range(100):
    add.delay(i, i, results)
```

Wait a few seconds before printing (while the consumers do their work) and be aware that results may came up out of order.

Method task.delay will return a celery.result.AsyncResult instance. Before using AsyncResult.result you should check for AsyncResult.state == SUCCESS.

Your final print loop could be:

```
for result in results:
    while not result.state.ready():
        time.sleep(secs)
    if result.state == u'SUCCESS':
        print result.result
    else:
        print "Something Rotten in the State of Denmark..."
```

This is (almost) the same as:

```
for result in results:
    print result.get()
```

Look at [TaskSets](http://celeryq.org/docs/userguide/tasksets.html#sets-taskset), they are better than storing results in a list.

In practice people store results in the database and place the wait loop in the client that will then hammer the server via AJAX every few seconds until completion.

Comment: @Paulo: thanks for your reply! Point I wanted to make is that the tasks remain in `PENDING` status and never turn to `SUCCESS`... and there seems to be a pattern among the tasks. I agree with all the points you have made in your reply, but I still can't get those tasks to return a value.

Comment: @Paulo: btw would you have any idea why some tasks fail to be picked up by cam? Could it be that they get executed too fast to be cought?

Comment: @RadiantHex: assuming you have task.ignore_result == False, what happens when you use result.get() instead of result.result?

Comment: @RadiantHex: what about watching `/path/to/yourapp/manage.py celeryd -l info`? Any hints?

Comment: @Paulo: thanks Paulo! I'm setting up a virgin setup with vmware, and set everything up from scratch and retry :)

Comment: @RadiantHex: It is hard to tell without seeing your results. BTW, who is the beauty in your avatar?

Comment: @Paulo: oh my god! New setup and everything works perfectly... the old one was a pretty new setup too. :|

Comment: @Paulo: now it runs bloody perfect :| Thanks Paulo!!